# Not Receiving Info using Open with of Gdrive API

Tags: google-drive-api

When I click the option for my app in the Drive Open with menu, it shows a permission screen, but after approving it redirects to the specified open url without the information. It also doesn't remember the permission.

I have enabled "Automatically show OAuth 2.0 consent screen when users open my application from Google Drive", with the web client id.

I have set the open and redirect url: https://5b731c1e1fdf82d3999598037306976a2b78d26c.googledrive.com/host/0B9_ds1FPyRuZfnE1bS1zQjVnVjNfZ0U0YkhBMXZBZlFuYzVqRlRTUmg3eGk4Y3JqcHlrNHc

I have set secondary opening html and js.

I have a Chrome extension with its id: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djgbpefmeilclncmpgjknlanpdmkopbn

Comment: we cant guess without code...

Comment: What code are you wanting?

Comment: show anything you have. code, urls, manifest and such

Comment: whats the relationship with the chrome extension? thats not how one would implement an "open with..."

Comment: The Chrome extension adds it to Drive.

Comment: show us how you configured the console key (type of ket, valid redirects and such)

Comment: also, not sure if one would need to be signed-into chrome to make the extension oauth part work correctly.

Comment: The redirect url is posted above. Origin is same ending at host.

Comment: are you sure that google drive hosting is not causing an extra redirect that loses url parameters or # parts?

Comment: It might be, but I don't know how I would be able to determine that.

Comment: in chrome debugger network activity

Comment: That looks right, it shows 301 moved permanently.

Answer (score 0):

per our comments chat, the issue is that Google Drive hosting is doing an extra redirect that loses url parameters or #fragment parts.

look into hosting in appengine as a static site. most likely you won't go over the free quotas unless you have many thousands users daily with a lot of network traffic.